# Is git (GitLab/GitHub) suitable for use in an industry with a very high large project turnover

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab

I work in a fruit-machine company. We have what I suspect is a very rare use-case requirements for our version control....

Each *game* has about 250 megabytes of resources (.png's .wavs and .mkv's).
In this industry, games have very short shelf-lives, We are constantly churning out new games.. Up to 1 game per developer per week. We have hundreds of games, each with 250 megs of graphics in the repository.

Although most games will be played for a week, fail to attract customers and be forgotten about, we NEED to keep the code just in-case it is still live somewhere on the planet, and needs to be supported. Deleting repositories is NOT an option.

Can Git cope with this kind of work-load?
I see that GitHub / GitLab have relatively cheap plans, and offer *unlimited* repositories... But I suspect that after we migrate a few hundred gigabytes worth of SVN to their servers, they might be a little upset !?

Goes anyone have any experience with similar requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way is to contact GitLab / GitHub themselves, as most certainly they'll know how many repositories / space "unlimited" really is to them...

https://about.gitlab.com/contact/

https://enterprise.github.com/sn-contact

You could of course host your own git project yourself if github / gitlab doesn't suit your needs.

cheers

Comment: Thanks. I tried contacting them first. But they just parrot what the pricing page says - *Unlimited*.   
Some sales-person reading off a script is not enough of a guarantee for me.

Feature wise, the cheapest plan is good enough... But if i were to purchase that, then export 200 gigabytes to their servers, I fear they may want to terminate my account.

As you say, i will probably have to host this myself... But our tiny company does not have IT support.. and we really cant spare developer time maintaining the server.

Answer (score 0):

It’s ok to use github/gitlab, but below aspects should be noticed:

1. You should manage the large files and binary file in [**Git LFS**](https://git-lfs.github.com/) (such as .png, wavs etc).
2. VCS is designed to manage different version for a certain project so that the changes for the project can be traceable. Since you need to develop hundreds of games, you can’t manage all of them in the same repo. it's better to use **a game per repo or similar games manage in same repo but located in different branches**. So that you can find the game you developed easily and the repo size not increase rapidly.